# Cache images from API (Unsplash) React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, caching, react-native-flatlist, image-caching

I search for images and fetching them from UnSplash API but I want to cache images. Suppose I am getting 30 images I want to cache them all and store them. If I search for that same image again I want to display them

For example : I searched for **CAT** and I am displaying those images using `FlatList` now I want to cache them in such a way if my device is offline I can fetch those images back in my system even after restarting the application.

React Native - 0.62.2

Comment: I never used this package, but it seems [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) handle cache for you

Comment: It handle cache but not as per the requirements I stated above